# barcode 128 TTF font does not get recognized by the barcode reader

Tags: fonts, barcode, barcode-printing

[image: Barcode Screenshot][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJPEd.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJPEd.png) http://www.fonts2u.com/code-128.font?ptext=0001023813752&submit=Submit

I downloaded the code-128.ttf true type font on a Windows 7 machine.

After the above 128 ttf font installation, I opened a word document and entered the number 0001023813752. Then, I selected the number, right click on the number and changed the font type to the new installed code-128.ttf.

It does change the number to look like a barcode, but the issue is when I try to scan it using a barcode reader gun or any barcode reader mobile app, it does not get recognised. Meaning, there is nothing happening after holding the reader over the barcode so long.

But If I try to generate a barcode online for the same number in https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/index.php, the barcode gets recognized by the reader.

Please advice what could cause this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

128 True type Font always need to be encoded so that the barcode generated can be recognised by a barcode reader(unlike 39 Font type). Due to this, we have dependency on a third party encoder software.

Hence we have decided to use the barcode generated using the 39 TTF font type.

Thanks